# Not getting response from google's geolocation API

Tags: api, post, google-api, geolocation

I'm trying to get my latitude and longitude using Google's Geolocation API

This is what the documantation indcates:

> [Google Geolocation Documantation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/overview?hl=en_US)

This is my `POST` request to get the data

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=API_KEY",
  dataType: "application/json",
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  data: JSON.stringify({considerIp: true}),
  success: function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  },
});
```

but I get a `404` response status:

`XHR POST https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=API_KEY  [HTTP/3 404 Not Found 101ms]`

although I can see on my Google Cloud platform that the requests are correctly made, but returned with an error.

What am I missing?

Comment: 404 is a response It means your doing something wrong.  Where is the request body? we need to see what you are sending.  There is not enough code here to preproduce the issue.

Comment: @DaImTo this is exactly what I am sending :D . I just created my API key and made the post request according to the documantation. I'm stuck here.

Comment: Note the section of the documentation where it states "The request body must be formatted as JSON. The following fields are supported, and all fields are optional, unless otherwise stated:"

Comment: Check this you are missing the post data https://stackoverflow.com/a/50572197/1841839

Comment: Yeah still not working. Is this API limited to cellphones?

Comment: I just tested it with postman and it works fine so i dont think so.  Edit your question and include your code if you have changed it to add the request body.